# Spectogram to 2D Graph for Wavelets in R

Tags: r, wavelet

I am a newbie to using wavelets. I have done some background research on how to implement them in R. To do this I have used Example 4.2 from Practical Time-Frequency Analysis book by Carmona, Hwang and Torresani. The code is as follows.

```
library(Rwave)
sing <- numeric(256)
sing[31:60] <- (sqrt(1:30)/sqrt(30))
sing[60:90] <- 1
sing[140] <- 0.5
sing[200] <- 0.5
sing[201] <- -0.5
plot(sing,type="l", main="Test CWT Data")
cwtsing<-cwt(sing,5,12)
cwtsing
```

I have two questions :-

1. Is there a way to use another “basis” wavelet? This example uses the Morlet wavelet but could a db4 or sym4 wavelet be used somehow?
2. The spectrogram produced by this R code has log(scale) on the y-axis. Is there a quick way to change the appearance of the graph like is done for question 2 (see rainbow coloured 2D graph) in the following link. 
   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34333/extracting-information-from-the-result-of-continuouswavelettransform

I know I can manually write an algorithm to do a scale to frequency conversion but I was hoping there would be a quick solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanking anyone in advance.